# Transactionally changing Exchange on consumer acknowledgment?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want RabbitMQ to send acknowledged message to another Exchange. Is it possible?

I can do this in code.
either:

```
consume
ack
send
```

or

```
consume
send
ack
```

Both ways are not perfect. In the former one resend is not guaranteed, and in the latter one duplicates can occur. Can Rabbit do the job of moving message from one exchange to another transactionally when it receives `ack`?

Comment: I don't understand this. Do you want to "forward" the message?

Comment: @cantSleepNow Yes, and forwarding should be the result of ack